# how to remove folders in azure app service - avoid timeout?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a console app running as a webjob.
over time , the  program has been creating many folders
if i say "dir" i get timeout.
if i try to delete , i get timeout
how to i get rid of the folders?

example :
process [9232] terminated! Press ENTER to start a new cmd process.

I tried to delete the files with a batch file (below) but it times out .
forfiles /P D:\home\xx\Runs /M * /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE del @file"

forfiles /P D:\home\xx\Runs /M * /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rmdir /S /Q @file"

Comment: Use the ***rmdir directoryname /s /q*** command in Kudu Console to delete the directory

Answer (score 1):

App services have a neat feature available called Kudu console allowing you to browse catalogs and manipulate folders and files.

1. Go to the app service console and find an "Advanced Tools" option and click on Go.

[image]

2. New tab will open, at the top you will find menu. Click on cmd or powershell to enter shell. I assume you are running Windows App service plan, but the steps are similar for Linux based service plans.
   [image]
3. Now you can either use UI at the top to delete files/folder or run some commands.
   [image]

In general Kudu is a pretty helpful tool. If you want to learn more about it please check docs [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki).

Comment: Kamil, I was in Kudo when I got the timeout   :-(
Anybody else have a tip?

Comment: Can you try deleting less files at once? If not, I think the easiest way would be to redeploy the app what would clear working directory.

Comment: but D:\home is persistent storage, shared by all instances.